# node.js logs to postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, logging

I have some scripts working on my server. Sometimes they give some errors. I want to write a log.js which will collect these logs and send them to database with certain column names. Is there any library about it? I made research and found log.js library and winston. But couldn't figure out how to use them. Thanks for helps.

Answer (score 3):

winston is a very capable logging library. It uses "transports" for logging out put. You can add a transport for the console, papertrailapp.com or postgres.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston

https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-postgresql